# Не работает цикл в jsp

Tags: sql, hibernate

В простом *CRUD*-приложении (*Spring, Hibernate, H2 embedded*) не отображает в цикле демо-данные (в данном случае, список организаций).

index.jsp:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>TestWebApp</title>
</head>
<body>
<table align = "center" class="table" cellspacing='0'>
<tr>
<th valign = "top">List of Organizations</th>
</tr>
<c:forEach items="${organizations}" var="organization">
<c:url var="edit" value="/src/main/java/model/edit?id=${organization.id}" />
<c:url var="delete" value="/src/main/java/model/delete?id=${organization.id}" />
<tr>
<td><c:out value="${organization.name}" /></td>
<td valign = "top"><a href="${edit}">Edit</a></td>
<td valign = "top"><a href="${delete}">Delete</a></td>
</tr>
</c:forEach>
</table>
<table align = "center" class="table" cellspacing='0'>
<tr>
<td><a href="${add}">Add</a> an organization</td>
</tr>
</table>
<br>
<%--<c:if test="${empty organization}">
<table align = "center" class="table" cellspacing='0'>
<tr>
<td><td>There are currently no organizations in the list. <a href="${add}">Add</a> an organization.</td>
</tr>
</table>
</c:if>--%>

</body>
</html>
```

Controller:

```
import id.web.antin.dao.OrganizationDAO;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class HomeController {

    @Autowired
    OrganizationDAO organizations;

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String hello(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("organizations", organizations.listOfOrganizations());
        return "index";
    }
}
```

DAO:

```
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import java.util.List;

@Repository
public class OrganizationDAOImpl implements OrganizationDAO {

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    private Session getCurrentSession() {
        return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    }

    @Transactional(readOnly = false)
    public void addOrganization(Organization organization) {
        getCurrentSession().save(organization);
    }

    @Transactional(readOnly = false)
    public void editOrganization(Organization organization) {
        Organization organizationForUpdate= getOrganization(organization.getId());
        organizationForUpdate.setId(organization.getId());
        organizationForUpdate.setName(organization.getName());
        organizationForUpdate.setCountry(organization.getCountry());
        organizationForUpdate.setAddress(organization.getAddress());
        organizationForUpdate.setPhone(organization.getPhone());
        organizationForUpdate.setMarketCap(organization.getMarketCap());
        getCurrentSession().update(organizationForUpdate);
    }

    public Organization getOrganization(int id) {
        Organization organization = (Organization) getCurrentSession().get(Organization.class, id);
        return organization;
    }

    @Transactional(readOnly = false)
    public void removeOrganization(int id) {
        Organization organization = getOrganization(id);
        if(organization != null) {
            getCurrentSession().delete(organization);
        }
    }

    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public List<Organization> listOfOrganizations() {
        return getCurrentSession().createQuery("from Organization").list();
    }
}
```

Сам  sql:

```
CREATE TABLE Organizations (
  id_organization int identity,
  name varchar(255),
  country varchar(255),
  address varchar(255),
  phone varchar(255),
  market_cap varchar(255),
  primary key (id_organization));

INSERT INTO Organizations(
  id_organization, name, country, address, phone, market_cap)
VALUES (1, 'Company', 'Russia', 'M', '+1000000', '1000000');
```

Output:

> Hibernate: select organizati0_.id as id1_0_, organizati0_.address as address2_0_, organizati0_.country as country3_0_, organizati0_.marketCap as marketCa4_0_, organizati0_.name as name5_0_, organizati0_.phone as phone6_0_ from Organization organizati0_

Как это исправить?